# wxPython on system tray draw

Tags: python, wxpython, system-tray

I got a little issue concerning wxPython and the system tray.
Well, all I use is the system tray and I want to have it call a function right after the system tray got drawn, but EVT_PAINT seems to have no effect on the tray for me.
Anyways, here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
import wxversion
wxversion.select('2.8')
import pynotify,subprocess,wx,os,json

#config
TRAY_TOOLTIP = 'Backups'
PROG_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


class Config:
    def __init__(self):
        self.readFile()
    def readFile(self):
        jsons = ''
        searchingJson = True
        f = open(PROG_DIR+'/config.json')
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        self.json = json.loads(lines)

pynotify.init("Backups")
def backup():
    sysTray.set_icon(PROG_DIR+'/loading.png')
    pynotify.Notification("Backups","Starting Backup",PROG_DIR+'/backup.png').show()
    if subprocess.call(["rsync","-a",config.json['backup_dir'],"--exclude",".*",config.json['remote_dir']]):
        pynotify.Notification("Backups","Backup Failed",PROG_DIR+'/backup.png').show()
    else:
        pynotify.Notification("Backups","Backup complete!",PROG_DIR+'/backup.png').show()
    sysTray.set_icon(PROG_DIR+'/backup.png')

def create_menu_item(menu,label,func):
    item = wx.MenuItem(menu,-1,label)
    menu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU,func,id=item.GetId())
    menu.AppendItem(item)
    return item

class TaskBarIcon(wx.TaskBarIcon):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TaskBarIcon,self).__init__()
        self.set_icon(PROG_DIR+'/backup.png')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT,self.initial_backup)
    def CreatePopupMenu(self):
        menu = wx.Menu()
        create_menu_item(menu,'Start Backup',self.on_backup)
        menu.AppendSeparator()
        create_menu_item(menu,'Exit',self.on_exit)
        return menu
    def set_icon(self,path):
        icon = wx.IconFromBitmap(wx.Bitmap(path))
        self.SetIcon(icon,TRAY_TOOLTIP)
    def on_exit(self,event):
        wx.CallAfter(self.Destroy)
    def on_backup(self,event):
        backup()
    def initial_backup(self,event):
        print 'test'
def main():
    app = wx.App(False)
    sysTray = TaskBarIcon()
    app.MainLoop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Nothing gets printed to the terminal.
Thanks for help!

Comment: what are you actually trying to accomplish?  .... you can see here

http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.TaskBarIcon-class.html

that it does not inherit from wxWindow ... as such has no EVT_PAINT ...

Comment: As you maybe noticed, it is some backup software I am making, and I want to make it run the backup automatically right after it started.

Comment: I would just spawn a thread to do it in your on init ... and you can poll thread.is_running to see if it has finished yet ...